# php-mode overwrites c-basic-offset customization, how can I set it to my preferred value?

Tags: customization, php-mode

GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21)
PHP-Mode: https://github.com/emacs-php/php-mode, Version: 1.21.1

I customized `c-basic-offset` to 2.

When I open a php-File, php-mode is automatically invoked (by `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode))` in .emacs) and `c-basic-offset` is set to 4. By `C-h v c-basic-offset` I can clearly see: 2 is recognized as global customization but the buffer-local setting is 4. Obviously, php-mode is doing this.

How can I alter this behaviour? Either, php-mode invocation does not touch c-basic-offset? Or, after loading php-mode a hook sets it back to 2.

Every attempt from my side failed so far.

Answer (score 3):

This code in .emacs did the job:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (make-local-variable 'c-basic-offset)
        (setq c-basic-offset 2)))
```

I failed previously because I tried to change the global `c-basic-offset`. That didn't help as the local variable generated in php-mode took precedence (I think).

Comment: You most likely have the `setq-local` macro available to you to simplify that code.  It's also better to use named functions in hooks rather than lambdas (easier to inspect, remove, modify, etc).